# Android Google Places show places from bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get all the places from the current camera bounds of Google Maps.

I managed to do this using the AutoComplete API but I have to insert a query for it to work.

So to my question, is there a way to do this, either use AutoComplete API without query or some other way?

Comment: I don't think you could make the Place Autocomplete work without the query as it is one of the required parameters. I don't see other options either in doing autocomplete without a query.

Comment: Okey.. :( I guess i have to look further.

Comment: Do you know if there is an other way to archive this? Maybe using some other API?